# How to update BIOS with efi?

Tags: bios

We have a GA-H61M-DS2 rev 2.0 motherboard. It has an "F4" BIOS. We went to the vendors website:

```
http://hu.gigabyte.com/products/page/mb/ga-h61m-ds2rev_20/download/bios
```

and downloaded "F7", the latest BIOS version.

We already tried: 
1) "Efiflash.exe H61MDS22.F7" command from windows 7/32bit, it said nothing, the command line just flashed for a second..

2) boot the win7 in "dos" mode (...) but the same thing happened.

**Q: How can we upgrade the BIOS? There aren't any ways for it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the Gigabyte @Bios utility. you can get it here: http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4073#utility be sure to select your OS.

and here are some [instructions](http://www.gigabyte.com/MicroSite/121/tech_a_bios.htm) for using it. they are for a differant board type, but should work fine for you. just be sure to dl @Bios from the link above, not the link in the instructions